# Footer seperator has different color on Stack Overflow and Meta

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design

Stack Overflow and Meta's footer seems to be identical, except that the colors of the separators seem to be different. This is obviously a huge oversight that should be corrected immediately, even worse than the Venn diagram bug and the giant 'S' Jeff-comes-to-your-house-and-bash-you-over-the-head pluralization bugs.

Meta Stack Overflow footer:

[image]

Stack Overflow footer:

[image]

Comment: this bug is a travesty, an affront to human dignity.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find meta's one vastly superior aesthetically.

Comment: @Mat I actually prefer SO's, for consistency.